# Not able to click button on wordpress form

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

My HTML

```
<button type="button" class="button media-button button-primary button-large 
 media-button-select">Select File</button>
```

My Selenium Java code

```
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 30); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Select File')]"))).click();
```

Comment: See if it's in different iframe , or in different page than you landed in , etc